# Regular expression match b but not <br/>

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a text string

```
bus<br/>
```

How can I use regular expression in JavaScript to match any "b" characters except the b within the 
 html tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: How about the b in `<body>` ,  `<b>` , `<bold>` or `<table>`? Now you can see how the rabbit hole deepens.

Comment: What are you trying to do here exactly? What is the actual purpose of the code?

Comment: @KHsueh Please heed  the link Epascarello provided. There are almost always better ways to deal with this than regex. Regex is just the wrong tool to look at HTML Tags, period.

Comment: I was trying to do some keyword searching against a text string, the text string can contains only the br tag but no other HTML tags.  When a match is find, the matching bit in the text string will be highlighted (by wrapping the matching bit with a strong tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most regex engines, to match `b` except in `<br/>` use negative look behind/ahead:

```
(?<!<)b(?!r/>)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/UN6vLs7CNH).

However, javascript doesn't support look behinds. But it does support look aheads - you'll probably be OK with just:

```
b(?!r/>)
```

For this simplified version to fail, the input would have to contain `br/>` (without the open angle braket), which seems unlikely.